# openweathermaps weather map layer not showing correctly on openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openweathermap

Hey everyone i am trying openweather weather map layer to display in openlayers but cant seem to render it correctly can some one help as to what is wrong with my code. The App id is my api key and i am not sure what to send in {x}, {y} section of the url so i have send 8 as the value. Note these are basic weather maps provided for free tier in openweathermaps weather maps 1.0

```
var layer_cloud = new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            // Replace this URL with a URL you generate. To generate an ID go to http://home.openweathermap.org/
            // and click "map editor" in the top right corner. Make sure you're registered!
            url: 'https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/wind_new/4/8/8.png?appid=APP_ID'
          })
      });
```

the layer renders but it is not like the one shown in examples its just a pattern being repeated all over the map[image: weather map layer]

here is the layer without the base layer [image]

Comment: You use `ol.source.XYZ(` but you put fixed values in png (so also possible wrong scale)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi can u please provide an example

Comment: Check the documentation of XYZ. It will take the same time for you and for me (since years I'm not using openlayers).

Comment: You are displaying tile 4/8/8 at all locations, you should specify `url: https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/wind_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`